# Does the rational power series ring $\mathbb{Q}[[X]]$ embed as a ring into the field of real numbers?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

The title says it all. I'm wondering if the power series ring $\mathbb{Q}[[X]]$ (with rational coefficients) embeds as a ring into the field of real numbers. There are various topologies one might consider here, but I'm curious if there is an algebraic embedding.

Comment: You do mean "formal" power series, without any convergence notion?

Comment: @paulgarrett yes, this sounds clear from the formulation

Comment: @YCor, yes, I would have presumed so, except that the questioner's text just said "power series"...

Answer (score 51):

$\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$The answer is no!

**Lemma** Let $f(x) \in \QQ[[x]]$ with $f(0) =c^2$ for some nonzero rational $c$. Then $f(x)$ is a square in $\QQ[[x]]$.

**Proof** Use the Taylor series for $\sqrt{c^2+u}$ about $u=0$. $\square$

Therefore, if $\phi : \QQ[[x]] \to \RR$ is a ring homomorphism, then $\phi(1/n^2 + x) = 1/n^2 + \phi(x)$ must be a square for every positive integer $n$, and so $1/n^2 + \phi(x) \geq 0$ for every positive integer $n$.

Similarly, $\phi(1/n^2 - x) = 1/n^2 - \phi(x) \geq 0$ for every positive integer $n$.

So $-1/n^2 \leq \phi(x) \leq 1/n^2$ and we conclude that $\phi(x)=0$, so $\phi$ cannot be an embedding.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks.

Comment: Summary: if $A$ is a unital $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra and $u\in A$ is such that $u+1/n^2$ and $-u+1/n^2$ is a square for all $n\ge 1$ then every homomorphism $A\to\mathbf{R}$ vanishes on $u$, while $u=x\in\mathbf{Q}[[x]]$ satisfies this property.

Comment: Very cool! Do you have any idea whether there are non-trivial homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} [[X]] \to \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: @AchimKrause  Check out the images of $1\pm cx$ for a large $c\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: I don't know whether I understand correctly: this even applies to the henselization of $\mathbb Q[X]$ (or $\mathbb Z[X]$ as above) with respect to the ideal $(X)$? What about $\mathbb C$ in place of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Z.M With $\mathbb{C}$ in place of $\mathbb{R}$, there is an embedding.  The point is that $\mathbb{C}$ has continuum transcendence degree, and $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ has continuum cardinality, so its fraction field is not too big.

Comment: Make that $1 \pm 4n x$, so that $\sqrt{1 \pm 4n x}$ has integer coefficients.@IlyaBogdanov

Comment: @Z.M Maybe a more basic thing to point out is that, in $\mathbb{C}$, every element is a square, so this proof can't get off the ground. This is the same trick as the standard problem "show that $\mathbb{R}$ has no nontrivial field automorphisms". (Solution: Any such automorphism would preserve the property of being a square, hence the property of being positive, hence would preserve the standard order on $\mathbb{R}$; also, any such automorphism would fix $\mathbb{Q}$.) By contrast (assuming Choice), $\mathbb{C}$ has tons of field automorphisms.

Comment: Details about $\mathbf{Z}[[x]]$. (1) If $u+nv$ is a square for every $n\in\mathbf{Z}$ then every homomorphism to $\mathbf{R}$ maps $v$ to 0. (2) $u=1$, $v=4x$ works, i.e. $1+4nx$ is a square. Indeed $\sqrt{1-4x}=1-2x\sum_{k\ge 0} c_kx^k$ with $c_k$ Catalan numbers.

Comment: Nice discussion! So we can say that for any unital subring $D$ of $\mathbb{R}$, any homomorphism from $D[[X]]$ into $\mathbb{R}$ has the form $\varphi(a_0+a_1X+\cdots)=\zeta(a_0)$, where $\zeta\colon D\to\mathbb{R}$ is a homomorphism. Further, the only homomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}[[X]]$ into $\mathbb{R}$ are the zero map and the map sending every power series to its constant term.

Answer (score 16):

Some commentary on David's very nice [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/428888/2383) that might provide some useful context. If $D$ is a subring of $\mathbb{R}$ then it must be an integral domain and its field of fractions $\operatorname{Frac}(D)$ must also embed into $\mathbb{R}$ so must be an ordered field. As an ordered field it must be [Archimedean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Archimedean_ordered_field) in the sense that it has no infinitesimals (elements $\varepsilon$ satisfying $0 < \varepsilon < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$) since $\mathbb{R}$ is Archimedean. So we can rule out the possibility of an integral domain $D$ admitting an embedding into $\mathbb{R}$ if we can show that any ordering on $D$ contains an infinitesimal. (Of course many integral domains will not admit any ordering at all, which would be an easier argument, but this one does. The relevant keyword here is "[formally real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formally_real_field)".)

This is what David's argument does: the key is that squares are always non-negative, and from there David shows that this implies that $x \in \mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ is always infinitesimal, which is nicely intuitive. An example of an ordering is the lex ordering where a positive element is an element whose first nonzero coefficient is positive; for convergent power series this corresponds to the ordering where a positive element is an element which is positive on a sufficiently small neighborhood of the origin, which is an ordering that makes sense more generally for germs of real-valued continuous functions.

The corresponding question for embeddings into $\mathbb{C}$ is much easier: here we can appeal to the fact that uncountable algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$ are classified up to isomorphism by their cardinality. From here it suffices to check that $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ is small enough that the algebraic closure of its field of fractions is at most as large as $\mathbb{C}$, which is true, and then the conclusion follows. If we tried to imitate this argument for $\mathbb{R}$ we'd be led to constructing the [real closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) of the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ (which I believe is [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) with real algebraic coefficients) but unfortunately real closed fields don't enjoy the same property of being classified by their cardinality, and the presence or absence of infinitesimals (and towers of infinitesimals, e.g. we can have elements which are infinitesimally small with respect to other infinitesimals) is one way to see this. This has been discussed on MO previously, at [Are there as many real-closed fields of a given cardinality as I think there are?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12949/are-there-as-many-real-closed-fields-of-a-given-cardinality-as-i-think-there-are).

This suggests an interesting follow-up question:

> The $\mathbb{C}$ argument shows that the subrings of $\mathbb{C}$ are exactly the integral domains of characteristic $0$ with cardinality at most the continuum. Is there a similar characterization of the subrings of $\mathbb{R}$? They must be integral domains admitting an Archimedean order with cardinality at most the continuum; is this enough?

Comment: I'm confused by your notation. You seem to mix up between ordered field and orderable field. The order is not unique in general. What do you mean by Archimedean for an orderable field (the order not being given)?

Comment: @YCor: you're right that I'm being imprecise about orderability, I'll edit.

Comment: If I understand David's argument correctly, it implies that the henselization of $\mathbb Q[X]$ w.r.t. the ideal $(X)$ is also not embeddable into $\mathbb R$, which seems to be countable.

Comment: To answer your last question is yes. Subrings of $\mathbb R$ are precisely the integral domains which admit an Archimedean order. This is because the Archimedean property implies that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in its fraction field, from which a unique map into $\mathbb R$ arises.

Comment: @Z.M Or alternatively it is enough to consider the subring generated by the square roots involved in the proof, and this is countable.

Comment: @YCor I guess that this is not very different. If I remember correctly, the henselization is the subring of the completion under mild conditions like excellence, and here indeed, square roots suffice.